# Set ItemsSource of UWP ComboBox to ViewModel Property

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to set the ItemsSource of a UWP ComboBox to a property of the ViewModel, but I get an error:

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'componentsLookup' property not found on 'Orders.Component'
```

The relevant bit of XAML looks like this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:OrderPageViewModel x:Name="OrderPageViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<ListView
    Name="ComponentsList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox
                    ItemsSource="{Binding componentsLookup,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="ComponentCode"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The relevant bit of the ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class OrderPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    public List<Component> componentsLookup = new List<Component>();
```

**Edit 1:** The models look like this

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ProductCode;
    }
}
public class Component
{
    public Guid ComponentId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public string ComponentCode { get; set; }
    public string ComponentDescription { get; set; }
    public string ComponentColor { get; set; }
    public decimal  ComponentHeight { get; set; }
    public decimal ComponentWidth { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ComponentCode;
    }
}
```

How do I set the ItemsSource to `componentsLookup`

Answer (score 2):

Nested binding is what you actually want to do. Since the `ComboBox` is nested inside the `ListView`, `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox` need to be a sub collection of `ListView`. `componentsLookup` should be a property of class `Orders.Component` in your code snippet. You can use a nested source structure like follows for binding:

```
public class OrderPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
    {
        new Product
        {
            productname="productname",
            componentsLookup=new List<Component>
            {
                new Component {componentname="test1" },
                new Component {componentname="test2" }
            }
        },
          new Product
        {
            componentsLookup=new List<Component>
            {
                new Component {componentname="test1" },
                new Component {componentname="test2" }
            }
        }
    };
}

public class Component
{
    public string componentname { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public List<Component> componentsLookup { get; set; }
}
```

XAML Code

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:OrderPageViewModel x:Name="OrderPageViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
    <ListView Name="ComponentsList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding productname}"></TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="ComponentCode" ItemsSource="{Binding componentsLookup, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

More details please reference the [official data binding document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Sunteen - MSFT but this solution does not quite address the business case. Each product is made up of a list of components. This list of components is a subset of the complete list of all components. The complete list of all components `componentsLookup` is not a property of `Product`. As another example, in another control we want to assign a color to a component. The list of all colors cannot also be a property of `Product`. We need a way to assign an ItemSource to a ComboBox without the ItemsSource being a property of the model. This is a common business case.

Comment: @Vague could you please provide your entities (Product and Component class) ? You don't want a nested source but nested binding? Should you must nested the `ComboBox` inside a `ListView`?

Comment: I have added the models @Sunteen - MSFT. We are trying to prove if UWP is suitable for a LOB application. The code was generated for this exercise. The actual models belong to another team and we may not be able to make changes to them. We need to be able to provide the views what they need through ViewModels.

Comment: My apologies @Sunteen - MSFT I accidentally posted the wrong models. I have corrected that error.